# Can you please explain me the form_valid() function here?

Tags: python, django

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateView):
  model = Article
  template_name = "article_new.html"
  fields = ("title", "body") # new

  def form_valid(self, form): # new
   form.instance.author = self.request.user
   return super().form_valid(form)
```

I am reading a book and author is telling that to insert the author automatically we can use this function in our createview inherited class. But he didnt explained anything regarding this function. What is this for_valid() function? What it does? and specially the return line?

Answer (score 2):

> What is this `form_valid()` function? What it does? and specially the return line?

The method originates from the [**`FormMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin), which is mixed in class-based views with a form like a [**`CreateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) and [**`UpdateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView).

These views will, for a POST request first construct the form with the POST data, then check if the form is valid, and if it is valid call `.form_valid(form)` so with the valid form, and `.form_invalid(form)` if it is not.

So the `CreateView` will check if the form is valid, and thus the title and body are valid, and if so pass control to the [**`.form_valid(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid). Which will save the form, and then redirect to the success URL to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get architectural pattern* <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

In this specific case you thus will set the `.author` of the instance wrapped in the form to the logged in user. It is however not said that such user exists. You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequiredmixin-mixin):

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class ArticleCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'article_new.html'
    fields = ('title', 'body')  # new

    def form_valid(self, form):  # new
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 

`def form_valid(self, form): # new`

Define the function.

2)
`form.instance.author = self.request.user`

Sets the Article author as currently logged in user.

3)
`return super().form_valid(form)`

Outputs the result of `form_valid` function.